# Automatically change active tab?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following displays several tabs with UnitName labels. When an associated tab is clicked it causes a table associated with that tab to be displayed (javascript).

How would I change this so a particular UnitName is treated as the active one and display the associated table automatically as opposed to have to click the desired UnitName tab first?

```
foreach($unit_list as $unit)
{
echo '<li><a href="#unit'.$j++.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$unit['UnitName'].'</a></li>';
}?>

//the following doesn't happen until the javascript knows which tab is active

 <div class="tab-content">
 <?php $j=0;$i=0;
     foreach($unit_list as $unit)
     {?>

         <div class="tab-pane" id="unit<?php echo $j;?>"> 
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-color" id="deptTabs">
             <?php $userDept = 0; $k=$i; foreach($dept_list[$j] as $dept)
             {?>
                 <li
                     <?php
                     if($dept['Department']==$user_info[0]['Department'])
                     {
                         $userDept=$i;
                         echo "class=\"active\"";
                     }?>
                 >
                     <a href="#dept
                     <?php echo $i;?>
                     " data-toggle="tab">
                 <?php echo $dept['Description'];?></a></li>
                 <?php $i++;
             }
             $i=$k #put i back to the value it started at?>
         </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use .trigger() with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#dept_tabs li').each(function(i,v){
      if(i.hasClass('active')){
        i.trigger('click');
      }
   });
});
```

This will loop through all the li elements, find the one thats active,
And trigger a 'click' event on it.

This is assuming that you have a predefined 'click' event assigned to these tabs.

Ie...

```
 $('#deptTabs li').click(function(){
 // Show table here based on which tab was clicked
 });
```